# Lan - Wan Cascaded Router, no internet on Wan on secondary router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I configured a Lan-Wan cascaded router at my place, but the wifi on Router 2 as no internet access for some reason.

So, I can access internet fine from a wired device which connects to router 2. i.e. i disabled DHCP router 2, made sure the IPs of both routers are different, one is 192.168.0.1 and the other is 192.168.1.1.

Initially, I configured the Wan so that the SSID and password are exactly the same as router 1, as instructed on a lot of the posts i found online. But i kept getting connection drops, it turned out that connections on router 1 works fine but not on router 2.

So what I did was that I disabled the 5GHz band on router 1 and try to connect to the 5GHz band on router 2, this is how i can be sure that i am connecting to a particular router. this is when I saw "no internet access". I can access both routers fine when my machine is connected to the wifi on router 2, but not the internet.

Can anyone point me to the right direction here? ideally, I would like to use wifi on router 2 and just use router 1 for VOIP.

Thanks so much in advance
Paul

Comment: Don't cascade routers.

Comment: Sounds like you didn’t set up the WAN connection (should be DHCP client) on router 2 correctly. But you don’t want that setup anyway. Instead, use router 2 as an access point. // edit: Oh, it appears you’re already trying. Did you connect the network link to a LAN port on both routers? This is *imperative*.

Comment: I connect from a LAN port on router 1 to the internet port on router 2. I did try to do LAN - LAN, but somehow it screwed up the ip of router 2, that I couldnt find it after connect. Had to reset to factory setting to start over.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need AP with switch, not 2nd router.
But in your configuration (2 networks .. not 2 ip) this probably should look like that:
wanIP is gateway for 1st router, lan1: 192.168.0.0/24 with gateway 192.168.0.1 and have nat masquerade to wanIP
192.168.0.1 is gateway for 2nd router, lan2: 192.168.1.0/24 with gateway 192.168.1.1, and (if it is connected by wan port to 1st lan) should have nat masquerade to 192.168.0.1.
Both routers should have enabled DHCP with dedicated lan configurations, but on 2nd you should set DNS as IP 1st router if you cache DNS on it.
Edit:
1st DHCP configure devices in 1st lan:

```
IP in network: 192.168.0.0/24
MASK: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
DNS - if you cache it then: 192.168.0.1
    - if not: DNS_IP of your provider or some public DNS (google 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)
```

2nd DHCP configure devices in 2st lan:

```
IP in network: 192.168.1.0/24
MASK: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
DNS - if you cache it on 1st router you can set here 1st router IP: 192.168.0.1
    - if not: DNS_IP of your provider or some public DNS (google 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)
```

If you need communication from LAN1 to LAN2 you need add on 1st router static route to LAN2 by IP 2nd router .

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with networking, can't quite understand your suggestion up to the last sentence. I think i did try to use DHCP enabled on both routers, but it didnt work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all your advice.

I finally made it work:

1. factory reset router 2,
2. unplug the Cable that connects both routers.
3. login to admin site on router 2.
4. make sure i skip the auto configuration and choose manual setup
5. plug in the cable from router 1 (LAN port) to router 2 (Internet port)
6. wait for router 2 to pick up the internet signal,
7. configure router 2 as if you are connecting to the fibre box directly.

This was what i tried the very first time, the only difference was that I configured the WAN ssid and password to be exactly the same as router 1. But this time, I disabled the 5GHz band on router 1 and created 2 completely different SSID in router 2 and then let my device connect to separate routers.

in this case DHCP is enabled on both routers and devices are on completely separated networks.

I guess the initial drop i was experiencing was that the device "switched" network due to signal strength. or may be i was wrong about this?

Comment: Yeah, that’s exactly how not to do it. Because this way, devices can’t talk to each other properly.